# DragEvent.ACTION_DROP not being detected

Tags: android

For some reason, dropping View A onto View B is not detected.

The drag listeners do work, as it detects the start and end of a drag, both in the listeners of View A and View B.

It only detects ACTION_DROP when I test the app on a device/emulator using API v24 (Nougat 7.0), but testing on API v23 does not detect the drop event.

---

Code for starting the drag & drop for View A

```
private View.OnLongClickListener onRoutineLongClick() {
    return new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    view);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                view.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            } else {
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

---

onDragListener for View A

```
view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

        final View v = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();;

        Log.d("", "Action: " + dragEvent.toString());

        switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mBinImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                // Move back to position
                v.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mBinImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

                return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

---

onDragListener for View B

```
mBinImage.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

        if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {

            // Do stuff
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```